# Seed images to active record on a has_many_attached :photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

How to seed images to a model that has many attached images?

#place.rb

```
....
 name
 has_many_attached :photos
.....
```

#seed.rd

```
p = Place.create!(name: "New york")
     p.photo.attach(io: File.open('app/assets/images/tower.png'), 
     filename: 'tower.png', content_type: 'image/png')
```

This does not work

i have the tower.png image in my image assets
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the relationship between places and photos (files) is one-to-many, you have to use `place.photos.attach` to [attach](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Many.html#method-i-attach) images to the record. You can join the image path with `Rails.root` to generate the file path.

```rb
place.photos.attach(
  io: File.open(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/tower.png')),
  filename: 'tower.png',
  content_type: 'image/png'
)
```

Comment: errror ```syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>``` 
on this line ``filename: 'tower.png',``

Comment: i think it is more than a syntax error. i have tried many combinations

Comment: @foliwe83 I tried it locally and it worked fine for me. Can you share the error you're running into?

Comment: i have this error `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen`

Comment: @foliwe83 Can you update the question with your latest code?